# Could not ssh into AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am facing interesting problem. I have launched an ec2 instance which is ubuntu 14.04. I can ssh into it by providing key file like below.

```
ssh -i "xxxxx.pem" ubuntu@xxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But I thought of making another account in instance rather than using ubuntu(root) always which is not safe. So I have created another account on my name in server. And for more security I thought of creating private(`id_rsa`) and public(`id_rsa.pub`) key files. And put the public key in server `.ssh/authorized_keys` and I should be able to ssh from my new account from my local machine. Which is also worked. now I can ssh into server like below.

```
ssh naroju@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Now the problem comes. Although I can ssh into to it from my new account, I cannot ssh into server from my ubuntu(root) account. It gives below error.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

1. Why is it giving me this error?
2. I wonder why did it ssh into server from my new account, does not it require private key file(`.pem` file of AWS) ?

Comment: What is the full path of `.ssh/authorized_keys` that you added?

Comment: it is `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` in server

Comment: OK, if you changed it at `/home/ubuntu`, then you changed the key of `ubuntu` user. If you now want to login as `ubuntu`, you need to provide the private key corresponding to newly added public key

Comment: I just removed `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` and truied to ssh in providing `.pem` file . same result.

Comment: You can not remove it, you need a pair: the public one at `.ssh/authorized_keys`, the private one with your ssh client

Comment: I removed it. First of all I found `Ubuntu` is not root in server. root is `root`. As I said in the question I can ssh into server with my new account on my name.So I ssh ed into server. I have turned to root by `sudo su`. I am in root now. I moved to `.ssh/authorized_keys` by typing `cd /home/ubuntu/.ssh/` and `rm authorized_keys`. it is gone. Now I should ssh to server with ubuntu as I removed public key?

Comment: If you removed it form `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/`, you will not be able to login as ubuntu.

Comment: When I first launched server. It does not have `authorized_keys` file at all. I used to ssh in using `.pem` .now it should ssh right using the `.pem` file?

Comment: Solved the problem. I don't know how it worked. Thank you for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new user (eg `naroju`) on the instance, you should create a `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the new user's home directory:

```
$ sudo adduser naroju
$ sudo su - naroju
$ mkdir .ssh
$ chmod 700 .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then, edit the `authorized_keys` file and add the **public key**.

You can then login to the new user:

```
$ ssh -i naroju.pem naroju@IPADDRESS
```

Since you have modified the public key in the `ubuntu` user's home directory, you will need to login as `ubuntu` using the private half of the keypair you selected. You can then run the above commands.

See Amazon EC2 documentation: [Managing User Accounts on Your Linux Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html)